# Paste 4th column of separate files side by side in one file

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I want to loop through multiple subdirectories and parse a specific file (DOE.nas) that exists in all subdirectories. The parsing is to print the 4th columns into one output, side by side. Below is an example for just 2 subfolders.

```
(DOE.nas) in dir_1
PSHELL       217  136738     0.7  136738            
PSHELL      1786   13571     1.4   13571         
PSHELL      1605  136513    0.65  136513           
PSHELL      1623   13571     1.4   13571
```

```
(DOE.nas) in dir_2
PSHELL      1628  136733     1.3  136733       
PSHELL      2015  136514    0.75  136514        
PSHELL      2304  136513     1.5  136513         
PSHELL      2509   13571     1.2   13571
```

```
Desired output (out.txt)
 0.7   1.3
 1.4  0.75
0.65   1.5
 1.4   1.2
```

Here is my code and the error:

```
for FILE in */*.nas; do
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $4}' "$FILE" > tmp
    paste tmp >> out.txt
done
```

```
My out.txt is stacked up
 0.7
 1.4
0.65
 1.4
 1.3
0.75
 1.5
 1.2
```

Comment: `paste <(awk '{ print $4}' file1) <(awk '{print $4}' file2)`?

Comment: @Shawn: there are many subdirectories/files. I just mentioned 2 as an example

Comment: FWIW, A problem statement that begins with "I want to loop through multiple subdirectories and parse a specific file" is counterproductive for your situation. The core of your question does not matter whether the files are in a different, or the same, directory. You could put all of the *.nas* files in the same directory and your problem would be unchanged. In other words, you are not asking for help finding the files. You are asking for help transforming and merging the content of those files.

Comment: The shell redirection `>>` **appends** the stdout of a process to a file.

Comment: Don't you want the input file name at the top of each output column or some other indication of where the values in that column came from?

Comment: When you say "multiple subdirectories" - what order of magnitude is "multiple"? The answer for "tens" or "hundreds" would be different from the answer for "thousands" or more due to the potential for exceeding `ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing OP's comment about having to process more than 2 files ...

Assumptions:

- all input files have the same number of lines
- all input files have at least 4 white space delimited columns
- column values do not contain white space

Setup:

```
$ head dir_*/DOE.nas
==> dir_1/DOE.nas <==
PSHELL       217  136738     0.7  136738
PSHELL      1786   13571     1.4   13571
PSHELL      1605  136513    0.65  136513
PSHELL      1623   13571     1.4   13571

==> dir_2/DOE.nas <==
PSHELL      1628  136733     1.3  136733
PSHELL      2015  136514    0.75  136514
PSHELL      2304  136513     1.5  136513
PSHELL      2509   13571     1.2   13571

==> dir_3/DOE.nas <==
PSHELL      1628  136733     17.3  136733
PSHELL      2015  136514    20.75  136514
PSHELL      2304  136513     31.5  136513
PSHELL      2509   13571     16.2   13571

==> dir_4/DOE.nas <==
PSHELL      1628  136733     7.54 136733
PSHELL      2015  136514    12.3  136514
PSHELL      2304  136513    24.55 136513
PSHELL      2509   13571     -1.2   13571
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { lines[FNR]= lines[FNR] (FNR==NR ? "" : OFS) $4 }
END   { for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++)
            print lines[i]
      }
' dir_*/DOE.nas
```

**NOTE:** this replaces all of OP's current code (`for / awk / paste`)

This generates:

```
0.7     1.3     17.3    7.54
1.4     0.75    20.75   12.3
0.65    1.5     31.5    24.55
1.4     1.2     16.2    -1.2
```

Comment: thank you, this is an excellent solution. Is it possible to modify this script to print the name of directories as the header of each column?

Comment: @EverLearner add `FNR==1 { print "########", FILENAME }` to show you what `awk` sees as the incoming filename; in my case `FILENAME` has values `dir_1/DOE.nas`, `dir_2/DOE.nas`, `dir_3/DOE.nas` and `dir_4/DOE.nas`

Comment: @EverLearner it's frowned upon to update/add-to a question once you have answsers if simply because the new requirements tend to 'break' the answers you've already received; I'd suggest you take this answer, add some code to parse `FILENAME` as you see fit, and build out a variable named `header` (similar to the `lines[FNR]=lines[FNR] ...` code - above); if you have problems with your new/modified code then ask a new question

Comment: a very simple example: `FNR==1 { header= header (FNR==NR ? "" : OFS) FILENAME }`, then `END { print header; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print lines[i]}`; add code to parse out the unwanted parts of `FILENAME` as per your requirements

Comment: Thank you much for your solution and comments.

Comment: I modified your script (changed $4 to $2 in line 3) to extract and populate the 2nd column of input files with ONLY 2 columns ; but it did not work (no horizontal stacking).  Interestingly, it works for first column (using $1). Can you help what I missed?

Comment: @EverLearner I'd recommend you ask a new question, making sure to provide sample inputs, the latest copy of your code, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: I have a new thread for this and mentioned you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256653/horizontal-concatenating-of-last-column-of-same-files-in-different-directories?noredirect=1#comment136198824_77256653

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do this with `paste`, which does a horizontal merge of files.  This gives you a single file to extract fields from with the usual tools.

Two files, a and b:

```bash
[~]$ cat a
1 Peter 34243
2 Andrew 2333
3 James 44

[~]$ cat b
aaa One 13472374
bbbb Two 123612
cccc Three 32476234
```

Paste them together and you get an output with lines combined, delimited here with a space using `-d ' '`

```bash
[~]$ paste -d ' ' a b
1 Peter 34243 aaa One 13472374
2 Andrew 2333 bbbb Two 123612
3 James 44 cccc Three 32476234
```

Then you can extract fields with `sed`, `awk`, or most easily, `cut`.

```bash
[~]$ paste a b -d ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2,5
Peter One
Andrew Two
James Three
```

Answer (score 3):

With a pure `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{arr[NR]=$4;next} {print arr[FNR], $4}' dir_*/DOE.nas
0.7     1.3
1.4     0.75
0.65    1.5
1.4     1.2
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles. How would this script change if I have several DOE.nas files to parse in side-by-side columns?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens in the posted code:

- We loop over all the files `*/*.nas`. That's fine.
- For each file:

  - We extract the 4th column of the file into `tmp`. That's fine too.
  - With `paste tmp >> out.txt` we *append* `tmp` at the end of `out.txt`

This last step does not do what you want, because `paste` with a single file argument doesn't change anything in the input, and the `>>` operator *appends at the end of a file*.

To paste content horizontally, you would need to pass multiple arguments to `paste`. To fix the script with minimal changes, consider this:

```
for FILE in */*.nas; do
    awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $4}' "$FILE" > tmp
    [ -s out.txt ] || { mv tmp out.txt; continue; }
    paste out.txt tmp > tmp2
    mv tmp2 out.txt
done
```

Notice here that `paste` is used with two files, `out.txt` has the accumulated columns so far, `tmp` has the column of the current file, and we paste them together into a new temporary file `tmp2`.

I also added a condition to skip the pasting if `out.txt` doesn't exist yet, otherwise `out.txt` would have an empty first column.

This solution is about *clunky*: it uses 2 temporary files, and it's rather long. There are shorter and simpler solutions, each with their own trade-offs.

#### Alternative #1

If every `.nas` file has 5 columns, then you could paste all the input files together horizontally, and then use Awk to extract every 5th column starting from column 4:

```
paste -d '\t' */.nas | awk '{ printf $4; for (c = 9; c < NF; c += 5) printf "\t" $c; print "" }'
```

This solution requires that all files have precisely 5 columns.

#### Alternative #2

If every `.nas` file has the same number of lines, then you could extract the 4th column of all files, producing a single column, and then use `pr` to split that single column to as many columns as the number of `.nas` files:

```
files=(*/*.nas)
awk '{ print $4 }' */*.nas | pr -T -s$'\t' -${#files[@]}
```

If the columns in the input files are separated by TABs, then the last command can be a bit simpler using `cut`:

```
cut -f4 */*.nas | pr -T -s$'\t' -${#files[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming tab-separated data, you can do this with `coreutils` e.g. with the input from [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203036/1331399):
:

```
col=4
cols_per_file=$(head -n1 dir_1/DOE.nas | wc -w)
cols_per_line=$(paste dir_?/DOE.nas | head -n1 | wc -w)

paste dir_?/DOE.nas | cut -f$(seq -s, $col $cols_per_file $cols_per_line)
```

Output:

```
0.7     1.3     17.3    7.54
1.4     0.75    20.75   12.3
0.65    1.5     31.5    24.55
1.4     1.2     16.2    -1.2
```