# Horizontal concatenating of last column of same files in different directories

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to go through 800 subdirectories and parse the LAST column of a specific file (myfile.txt) with same name/structure in all subdirectories, and print these columns horizonatally in one single output file. Below is an example for 3 files.

```
(myfile.txt) in dir_1
Row1      44.4            
Row2      45.5        
Row3      46.2           
Row4      46.3
```

```
(myfile.txt) in dir_2
Row1      33.7
Row2      25.8
Row3      14.9
Row4      32.1
```

```
(myfile.txt) in dir_3
Row1      12.1
Row2      13.2
Row3      14.5
Row4      16.4
```

Thanks to [@markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203036/1331399), I modified his script as below. but the output is not what I expect.

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { lines[FNR]= lines[FNR] (FNR==NR ? "" : OFS) $2 }
END   { for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++)
            print lines[i]
      }
' dir_*/myfile.txt > out.txt
```

**Generated output:**

```
44.4            
45.5        
46.2           
46.3
33.7
25.8
14.9
32.1
32.1
12.1
13.2
14.5
```

**Expected output (corrected):**

```
44.4   33.7   12.1       
45.5   25.8   13.2  
46.2   14.9   14.5     
46.3   32.1   16.4
```

Comment: It works here. What kind of line-endings do your `myfile.txt` files have?

Comment: @Thor: sorry for my naivete, I believe it is ended with Return. How can I figure the line-ending type?

Comment: fwiw, using your sample file and current `awk` script I am able to generate the expected output

Comment: I don't see any way this code can print all of the values from the 1st file, followed by all the values from the 2nd file, followed by all values from the 3rd file; the only way I can see to generate the same 'wrong' output is with something like `awk '{print $2}' dir_*/myfile.txt`; are you sure the code you've posted here is the same code as on your system? if you cut-n-paste the code (from above) into your system, you're still not getting the desired output?

Comment: Its impossible for the code you posted to produce the output you posted from the input you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Using your input files in separate directories -

```
$: grep . ?/myfile.txt
a/myfile.txt:Row1      44.4
a/myfile.txt:Row2      45.5
a/myfile.txt:Row3      46.2
a/myfile.txt:Row4      46.3
b/myfile.txt:Row1      33.7
b/myfile.txt:Row2      25.8
b/myfile.txt:Row3      14.9
b/myfile.txt:Row4      32.1
c/myfile.txt:Row1      12.1
c/myfile.txt:Row2      13.2
c/myfile.txt:Row3      14.5
c/myfile.txt:Row4      16.4
```

This is trivial in `awk`:

```
$: awk '{line[FNR]=line[FNR]$NF"\t"} END{for(row in line)print line[row]}' ?/myfile.txt
44.4    33.7    12.1
45.5    25.8    13.2
46.2    14.9    14.5
46.3    32.1    16.4
```

Breaking that out:

`{ line[FNR] = line[FNR] $NF "\t" }`
`FNR` is "File Number of Record", so on line 1 it will be 1.
`NF` is "Number of Fields", so `$NF` is always the last field.
This will, on each line, assign to the array for this line any previous content (none for the first file), then catenate the value of the last field, then a tab (or any other delimiter you like.) This assumes all files will have the same number of lines; if that isn't true, then it complicates the logic a bit.

`END{ for (row in line) print line[row] }`
This assigns the index of each existing value in the array `line` to `row` and then uses it to `print` the content of that cell, which adds a newline at the end. It leaves the hanging delimiter; if that's a problem we can trim it by using
 `print gensub(/\t$/,"",1,line[row])`
instead of just
 `print line[row]`

`?/myfile.txt` could be any glob that generates the list of appropriate files. If you can't create a glob that works, we need to supply the list of files.

If you need arbitrary depth globbing, try setting `shopt -s globstar` first; then using `/base/path/**/myfile.txt` (as long as there are no `myfile.txt`'s under your `/base/path/` that you don't want to include.)

Comment: Looks like I didn't change much from the code he already had.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ruby to do that.

Everything, including the recursive globbing, is being done by Ruby.

You need to have enough memory to hold all the files in memory.

Given:

```
head **/myfile.txt
==> dir_1/myfile.txt <==
Row1      44.4            
Row2      45.5        
Row3      46.2           
Row4      46.3

==> dir_2/myfile.txt <==
Row1      33.7
Row2      25.8
Row3      14.9
Row4      32.1

==> dir_3/myfile.txt <==
Row1      12.1
Row2      13.2
Row3      14.5
Row4      16.4
```

You can do:

```
ruby -e 'di=Dir.glob("**/myfile.txt").
            map{|fn| File.open(fn).read.split(/\R/).
            map(&:split).
            map(&:last)}.flatten
rows=di.each_slice(3).to_a.length
di.each_slice(rows).to_a.transpose.each{|r| puts r.join("\t")}'
```

Prints:

```
44.4    33.7    12.1
45.5    25.8    13.2
46.2    14.9    14.5
46.3    32.1    16.4
```

Be sure to execute in a directory that is the parent of all the files of interest.

---

Suppose the files may be of different length, and you want a column for each file.

Given:

```
head */myfile.txt
==> dir_1/myfile.txt <==
Row1      44.4            
Row2      45.5        
Row3      46.2           
Row4      46.3

==> dir_2/myfile.txt <==
Row1      33.7
Row2      25.8
Row3      14.9
Row4      32.1

==> dir_3/myfile.txt <==
Row1      12.1
Row2      13.2
Row3      14.5
Row4      16.4
Row5      xxxx
```

You can do:

```
ruby -e '
fns={}
ARGV.each{|fn| fns[fn]=File.open(fn)}
loop do
    puts ARGV.map{|fn| fns[fn].eof? ? "NA" : fns[fn].readline.split.last}.join("\t")
    break if ARGV.map{|fn| fns[fn].eof?}.all?
end' **/myfile.txt | column -t
```

Prints:

```
44.4  33.7  12.1
45.5  25.8  13.2
46.2  14.9  14.5
46.3  32.1  16.4
NA    NA    xxxx
```